# Silverstripe - Requirements on another controller

Tags: controller, silverstripe, requirements

I have built an image gallery module using lightboxes and effects. What I want to do is include the css and js requirements on the GalleryController rather than the PageController but it doesn't seem to work.

I have a Gallery which extends DataExtension and then I have a GalleryController which extends Extension. Then in my _config file I point the ContentController to my GalleryController:

```
SiteTree::add_extension('Gallery');
Object::add_extension('ContentController', 'GalleryController');
```

The GalleryController is working as it is getting the Gallery objects for me.
It is the requirements on this controller that aren't working.

GalleryController:

```
public function init() {
    parent::init(); 

    //Load CSS requirements
    Requirements::css("ImageGallery/css/lightgallery.min.css");

    //Load Javascript requirements
    Requirements::javascript("ImageGallery/js/lightgallery.min.js");
```

Do I need to do something else to include requirements on another controller that isn't PageController?

Comment: Where do you place your calls to `Requirements`? Some code would help.

Comment: I have updated my code. I'm placing them in the init function on the GalleryController.

Comment: Is `GalleryController` a subclass of `Extension` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extensions in SilverStripe don't allow you to overload the public API, you can only augment it. It looks like this is what you're trying to do with the GalleryController extension.

In this case you'll see that [`ContentController::init` provides an extension point](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/3.6.0/code/controllers/ContentController.php#L105-L106) `contentcontrollerInit` on the SiteTree object - you should use that to add your requirements. This can be added to your Gallery DataExtension class:

```
# Class: Gallery.php
public function contentcontrollerInit()
{
    Requirements::javascript('...');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was after! One thing I noticed is that it loads before the PageController requirements do. Is there a way to have the Gallery requirements load after the Page requirements? The PageController loads the jQuery and then the Gallery page loads everything dependant on jQuery.

Comment: The `PageController::init` method will be called, and as long as you've added your Requirements call _after_ the `parent::init` call then the extensions should run first. If you want the extensions to run after, add your Requirements (e.g. jQuery) _before_ the `parent::init` call in `PageController`

Comment: Personally Id also suggest on renaming the class of extension also to avoid confusion as the extension it self isn't a controller as it extends Extension.